# How to get browser's content, including the window's menu bar, frame/border, and content below the fold?

Tags: screen, capture, dump

I remember in the early days of the web, there were books that included the whole browser window's title bar, menu bar, and even the border of the browser, and the content inside of it -- not just the current content in the window, but all the content even when scrolled down).

I'd like to be able to do that too...  is there a easy way to write a Win32 or Mac app to do that, or perhaps as a Firefox extension (add-on)?

(the browser menu bar and bookmark bar can either be real or fake -- no need to show my personal bookmarks on the bookmark bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write such an app on the OS X side using the [Webkit framework](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/index.html) for Cocoa.

.NET on Windows has it's own [WebBrowser and WebBrowserBase class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) that provides a programmable browser like widget. Check out the [DrawToBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserbase_methods.aspx) method of the WebBrowserBase class.

There are also several apps that already do that.

For Mac OS X there is [Paparazzi](http://derailer.org/paparazzi/) and [Little Snapper](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/littlesnapper/) that can do what you want.

For Windows check [SiteShoter](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_site_screenshot.html) and [Webshot](http://www.websitescreenshots.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use Firefox's [FireShot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5648) extension and then use Microsoft's Paint and Alt-PrtScr to add the surrounding chrome.